# Error in logging Expo from cli

Tags: react-native, expo

I am getting this error when i am logging into expo through cli

```
[exp] Error
at _formatAuth0NodeError (C:\xdl\src\User.js:757:14)
at C:\xdl\src\User.js:654:15
at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
at step
```

Comment: cool. We, however, cannot help you, since we can't reproduce it.

Comment: Please paste the full stacktrace. Looks like some of it got truncated.

Comment: @anu truncated part is of no use i am getting authorization error when i am logging with my expo credentials through expo command line...if anybody faced the same error and was able to resolve please help...i am following the steps mentioned on expo official site

Comment: I have the exact same error, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: No....I switched to gui application of expo

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce the same error:

- exp version is 47.1.1
- tried on node 6.11.5 and 8.9.1

```html
[exp]
[exp] Error
    at _formatAuth0NodeError (C:\xdl\src\User.js:757:14)
    at C:\xdl\src\User.js:654:15
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\Users\shamann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\exp\node_modules\xdl\build\User.js:188:191)
    at C:\Users\shamann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\exp\node_modules\xdl\build\User.js:188:402
    at <anonymous>
```